# Control Youtube video player using Javascript from FireFox addon

Tags: javascript, youtube, flash, youtube-api

I wrote a FireFox addon which has a button on the toolbar.
On click event, I am trying to find the EMBED element and try to call pauseVideo() on it, but it doesn't work.

I am sure the object I get is the EMBED so no doubt about that, because I display the 'src'

```
var p1 = content.document.getElementById("movie_player");
window.alert(p1.src);
```

The problem is pauseVideo() doesn't work:

```
try
{
p1.pauseVideo();
}
catch(e)
{
  window.alert(e); // this gives 'pauseVideo() is not a function'
}
```

Also, the 'allowscriptaccess' attribute is set to 'always'.
Any idea why it doesn't work? I am out of ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `enablejsapi` is set.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#enablejsapi

Comment: it is set, it's a youtube video

Comment: Just to make sure you're waiting for after the onYouTubePlayerReady event has happened, right.

Comment: @Greg Schechter you don't know firefox addons ? addons work different, and your answer is bad

Answer (score 0):

You need to use postMessage to communicate with Youtube player, something like this:

```
    var doc = content.document;
    var scpt = doc.getElementById("uniq_script_id");
    if (!scpt) {
        scpt = doc.createElement("script");
        scpt.type = "text/javascript";
        scpt.id = "uniq_script_id";
        var code = [
            'window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {',
            '  var cmd = e.data;',
            '  var player = document.getElementById("movie_player");',
            '  player[cmd]();',
            '}, false);'
        ].join('\n');
        scpt.textContent = code;
        doc.body.appendChild(scpt);
    }

    window.postMessage("pauseVideo", "*");
```

Comment: I tested your code, it is not working in addon, but working if I open developer console and insert your code. Why it is not working in addon ? I now how to attach script to page in addon, and your code is not working when is attached